# Optimising calling a method on all elements of list of objects

Tags: python, optimization

I have a list of objects and I want to loop through the list and call one method per object.  Clearly, this is over optimisation and more meant as a "oh, I wonder what's the fastest way" rather than "must have every cycle worth of speed". I can think of several ways to do this and ran some profiling on them giving me these results:

```
; ipython
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

 In [1]  class ook:
             def eek(self):
                 pass
             

 In [2]  lst = [ook(), ook(), ook(), ook(), ook(), ook(), ook(), ook()]

 In [3]  %timeit -n 10000 map(lambda x: x.eek(), lst)
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.17 µs per loop

 In [4]  %timeit -n 10000 [x.eek() for x in lst]
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.32 µs per loop

 In [5]  def test(lst):
             for x in lst:
                 x.eek()
                 

 In [6]  %timeit -n 10000 test(lst)
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.18 µs per loop
```

The standard loop approach seems to win in term of readability but the `map` solution looks a little faster.

Have I missed something?

Is there a better way?

Comment: personally I'd use `map` but it depends on the problem domain as some operations can be vectorised which leads to numpy/pandas objects

Comment: For me the "standard loop" solution is almost a whole microsecond faster. However I can't help thinking that this is over-optimisation; pick the one that is most readable.

Comment: If speed is important then it's best to reconstruct the problem so you can use numpy

Comment: @paddyg or c++ if speed is really important

Answer (score 3):

If you only wish to call all the functions in the list, the for loop should be the most efficient since it does not create a new list (it actually is the most efficient on my machine).

Note also, that in Python 3 the *map* solutions wouldn't work, because it creates generator that is evaluated later on.

Answer (score 1):

Using larger arrays (of 1000 ooks), the plain loop is faster (in my tests), followed by the list comprehension, and then (60 % slower) the map method.

The reason for the plain loop beeing fastest is (probably) that it doesn't have to collect the return values to a new list.  The reason for map beeing so slow is that it needs an extra function call (the lambda) for each iteration.

In real life, however, the overhead from any of these methods will probably be insignificant compared to the time spent in the actuall `eek()` method.

Answer (score 1):

@Sandathrion, in answer to your additional question in the comments "Could you create an answer with how to do that with the toy example above?" it's quite hard, as the toy example doesn't do anything, but if a nearly-as-simple example is used to change a class attribute from 0 to 1 over 1,000 objects:

```
import timeit

### values held externally in numpy array
setup = """
import numpy as np
N = 1000
class ook(object):
  def __init__(self, i):
    self.ook_index = i

ook_vals = np.zeros(N)

lst = [ook(i) for i in range(N)]
"""
fn = """
ook_vals[:] = 1
"""
print(timeit.timeit(fn, setup, number=10000) / 10000)

### values held in class instances
setup = """
N = 1000
class ook(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 0
  def eek(self):
    self.val = 1

lst = [ook() for i in range(N)]
"""
fn = """
for x in lst:
  x.eek()
"""
print(timeit.timeit(fn, setup, number=10000) / 10000)
```

the results are

```
3.43601703644e-06
0.00044386138916
```

i.e. the numpy method is a couple of orders of magnitude faster